# How to draw location which i am getting in an xml to my mapView?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, android-mapview

I want to display all the location for which i am getting lat and lang in an xml on my Map. And on click it should display the detail of the location.

Can you suggest any tutorial which deal with this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to add the annotations to your mapview.This is the class reference for [MKMapview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) . and this the [tutorial](http://codisllc.com/blog/zoom-mkmapview-to-fit-annotations/) for adding the annotations. and this is the sample [program](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WeatherMap/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009491-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) for adding  the annotations